# Spartan-6 LVCMOS33 input pin: can it take 5V without damage?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan-6

My Spartan-6 device has an input pin with `IOSTANDARD = LVCOMS33` as constraint.
If I accidentally or otherwise connect it to a 5 V signal, will the FPGA get damaged?
There is no current draw to this connection, it is just a voltage input.

Answer (score 3):

The absolute maximum input voltage for LVCMOS33 on spartan6 is 4.1V, anything higher than that (even for a short time) may damage your FPGA permanently.

Check out the info on:

[Spartan-6 FPGA Data Sheet: DC and Switching Characteristics](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds162.pdf)

Use a resistor in series or a voltage converter before connecting  5V source into any LVCMOS33 input of your FPGA.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  There are ESD protection diodes to Vccio and these will turn on if the pin is supplied with a voltage higher than Vccio.  It may be possible to add a series current limiting resistor and use the ESD protection diode is a clamp, but this is not recommended.  You should look in to using some sort of external level shift circuit to prevent damage to the FPGA pins.